# USB BULK IN endpoint address 0x81 or 0x01?

Tags: embedded, usb, host, bare-metal

I am implementing USB as a host to read the contents of a FAT32 file system. The Endpoint descriptor returns me 0x81 as IN endpoint address and 0x02 for OUT EP.

I am implementing this using the OHCI. The Endpoint Descriptor in OHCI has a 4bit field for the Endpoint as shown by the 'EN' field- 
[image]

**So does this mean my endpoint address are 0x02 for OUT and 0x01 for IN? these are there endpoint numbers for sure.**

I ask this because my Transfer Descriptor for accepeting data from the IN endpoint is failing and I am not able to figure out the reason yet.

Comment: Practically speaking it is context dependent - some APIs will use 0x81 for an input endpoint, some will use 0x1 with a separate explicit specification that is an input.

Comment: @ChrisStratton so that implies that 0x01 is correct, right? for this specification

Comment: Got it to work! there was issue in my DataToggle bits!
Thank you @ChrisStratton 

And using 0x01 works!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Chris, it depends on the context and using 0x01 works !